# Bootstrap-datepicker calendar not shown

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using 'Bootstrap-datepicker' this is my code :

```
<div id="sandbox-container" class="span5 col-md-5">
    <input class="form-control" type="text">
</div>

<script>

$('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    language: "fr",
    autoclose: true,
    toggleActive: true
});

</script>
```

I don't understand why it doesn't show calendar

Comment: Any JS errors on your console?

Comment: What is wrong ?  : https://jsfiddle.net/zlen/m5gyfntn/

Comment: It doesn't work to me !

Comment: are the dates not showing in french?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you didnt have the bootstrap-calendar cdn linked:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js
```

if you want other languages, add .XX before the min.

In your case it would be:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.0/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.fr.min.js
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/web_dever/m5gyfntn/4/)